# How to conditionally run javascript code using rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I run javascript code based on some condition in a controller? For example, I want to display javascript `alert`, when `params[:alert]` is present. How can I do this?

Comment: You'd wrap the JS in a conditional/value rendered by the action.

Comment: @DaveNewton, something like render empty span with some id, and if it exists run js code?

Comment: Just render *anything*, it could be a scriptlet around a script tag (which works, but I think it's gross), a value in a JS block, anything. It doesn't matter. That said, native alerts are pretty awful anyway.

Answer (score 4):

In your view file

```
<% if params[:alert] %>

<script>alert("Hello");</script>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do in your controller:

```
def some_action
 if condition
  @run_javascript = true
 else
  @run_javascript = false
 end
end
```

and then in your view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <% if @run_javascript %>
  alert('Something was wrong');
 <% end %>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#view page
<script>
    <% flash.each do |k,v| %>
        <% if k == "success" %>
            success("<%= v %>");
        <% else %>
            alert("<%= v %>")
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</script>
```

You need only `flash:{ alert: or success:}`

```
#controller
 respond_to do |format|
    format.html{ redirect_back(fallback_location: '/orders', flash: { alert: "custom message" } ) }
 end
```